# FILTER AlphaImageLoader for Chrome and FF

Tags: css

Hello I am a new one in CSS,

I have next code that working just in IE

```
   filer: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod= 'scale' , src= '/line/resources/middleRight.png' )
```

Does anyone know how to make this functionality work in FF and Chrome

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firefox & Chrome you have to write like this:

```
div {
  background:url(image);
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod= 'scale' , src= 'image' )
}
```

Read this article http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: thanks it is help a little but Chrome mark property -moz-background-sizing -webkit-background-sizing background-sizing like not support

Comment: It's not background-sizing. It's background-size check link for more